# indexing keys AND related columns or just keys to increase speed in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

So if I have an sql query like these:

```
SELECT title, document FROM docs WHERE id = "1" and type = "2"

SELECT title FROM docs WHERE id = "1" 

SELECT title FROM docs WHERE member = "foo"
```

to maximize speed for the first one i. would I have to index only the keys (id and type together? seperate?) ii. would I also have to index title and document (together,separate)

same type of questions apply for the second one, and for the third query i. would I have to index only member?
IM just trying to understand mysql retrieval and indexing.

Comment: All of that, and even more, explained at http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 indexes

```
(id, type, title)
(member, title)
```

- `id, type` makes `id` redundant
- adding title makes the index [covering](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/04/how-to-exploit-mysql-index-optimizations/)

Comment: so i would have to index the columns associated with the keys for speedier retrieval?

Comment: hmm. @gbn: so if i'm getting 9 columns, and has 2 where conditions, do i need to make an index with 11 columns?  Also does indexing a combination of type and id will make the id index accessible without type?

Comment: @Anush Prem: pretty much yes unless the WHERE clause matches the clustered index. Column order matters too id/type is different (and better for id only searches) to type/id

Comment: so lets say I index all the columns (*) in one table. Would that be enough for any type of query?

Comment: @Praneet Sharma: not really: the WHERE clause columns have to be on the left hand side

Answer (score 0):

1) Index both id and type together, but not title and document

2) Index id only

3) index member only

in other word you have to index {id}, {id, type}, {member}

Comment: so basically anything that is being looked up, not retrieved. (WHERE clause)

Comment: {id, type} makes {id} redundant.